# Did Balram really call Krishna "Munna"?

Tags: krishna, name, balarama

I had read around 3 years ago somewhere (can't find that website now) that while Krishna called Balram "Dau" (Brother), Balram affectionately refered to Krishna as "Munna" (Little Boy).

Can anyone point me to *any* source for the same?

Comment: I think "Dau" दाऊ and "Munna" मुन्ना are hindi words , and are  of modern origin.So its not possible for both of them to call each other by these exact phrases , as sanskrit was spoken at that time. But we might find , use of similar sanskrit words used by both during conversation.

Comment: You must have heard such dialogues in Tv serials.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and I get the idea. BTW, I'm sure it was some website, not TV series.

Comment: To close-voters: A question should be closed when it is not answerable. This can be answered just by saying what @SwiftPushkar said in the comments. This is not an off-topic question.